# Determine the probability of a conditional p.d.f

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

So the joint p.d.f is f(x,y) = $c(x^2 + y^2)$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $0\leq y \leq 1$

Now the steps I worked out is applying the formula $f(x|y) = \frac{f(x,y)}{f_{2}(y)}$

Which gave me 
f(x|y) = $\frac{3x^2+ 3y^2}{1+3y^2}$.

Assuming that is correct, the answer Pr(X$<\frac{1}{2}$|$Y=\frac{1}{2}$)should be $\frac{2}{7}$. 
I solved this to get that answer: $\int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{3x^2+ 3(\frac{1}{2})^2}{1+3(\frac{1}{2})^2}$
But the correct answer is $\frac{1}{3}$. I don't understand what I'm missing.

Comment: Seems good to me. Maybe you were calculating the wrong thing or the answer you were provided is wrong.